# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not getting how to solve this exception.

I am passing Resultset object to each thread.and doing some logic

My sample program is:

```
public class dataimport

{

  public dataimport()

          {

         connect(); /*connect to database 


         }

private void connect()

{

try
   {

       /* connected data base

        str="SELECT * FROM tablename where rownum<=5";


          rs1 = statement.executeQuery(str);

            while (rs1.next()) 
            { 

                    Runnable r = new MyThreadClass(rs1);

                                        System.out.println(new Thread().getName());

                                         new Thread(r).start();


            }               
}
```

Thread class

```
class MyThreadClass implements Runnable

 {

public MyThreadClass(ResultSet rs1) 
   {


     rs2=rs1; 

    }


 public void run() 
   {   

           int i=1;

               try

                   {        

                      while (rs2.next())

                {

                                date=rs2.getString("mydate");

                                System.out.println("mydate="+date);

                                }

        }
     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


}

}
```

If i add while (rs2.next()) in thread class,there will be no exception,but mydate it will

print only two insight of few records.

please can any one help me on this.

thank you in advance

Comment: How many threads are processing result set simultaneously?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve with this code? You spawn several threads that are all competing and iterating over the same result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. You are getting concurrency errors.

You get N results -> start N threads. Inside each thread, **you loop again** over the resultset. It makes little sense, and worse, it can happen that one thread checks that `rs.next` is true, enter to iterate, get suspended by another thread that finish the result set data and, when resuming, tries to read data from a resultset with no data.

The simplest (without changing the mechanics) solution would be putting the threads main loop in a synchronized loop, but that will cause a massive deadlock so you will end with the same performance as no threads.

As for you code, I think that what you really want is, in the principal loop, extract all the results into a data structure, and pass that data structure to each thread so it can deal directly with it (and no passing a shared result set object which causes such problems).